# How to add Button to userLocation callout?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I display a DisclosureButton in the userLocation (the blue dot) callout like the Apple Maps app does?

Now I just can change its title and subtitle, but I hope to provide custom callout views. Therefore, if I click the blue dot, it can display a button besides only title and subtitle.  In this way, when I click the button, it can guide me to another View.
I returned MKAnnotationView in viewForAnnotation when annotation == self.mapView.userLocation. However, the callout can display updated title and subtitle, but cannot show the button I added.

I really need this function, and I desire any help and suggestion!

Answer (score 10):

I've tried *camdaochemgio*'s solution, but it works only for the second tap. Here is a solution which will always work:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    for (MKAnnotationView* view in views)
    {
        if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        {
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the annotationView, set

```
myAnnotationView.canShowCallout=YES;
```

then add up to two buttons with

```
myAnnotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView=myLeftButton;

myAnnotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=myRightButton;
```

The buttons can be a normal button, a custom button, or one of the predefined types. Like this:

```
myAnnotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
```

Then add the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` method to handle taps.

Comment: Thank you Henrik, Ive been looking for this solution for hours.

Comment: How were you able to get a handle on the MKUserLocation's annotation view?

Comment: @mjisrawi you get it in - (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(CarAnnotation *) annotation . You have to check if the annotation is the blue dot like so: if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])

Comment: @Nicolae that gives you the annotation, not the annotation view.

Answer (score 1):

maybe late.
Here is solution. You implement the UIMapViewDelegete method as below:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]] && !view.rightCalloutAccessoryView) {
        view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    }
}
```

Comment: if you add the button every time you select the annotation view, isn't that a bit of an overhead? Also, you see the accessory button appear slightly after the annotation view does. Is there a way to stop that from happening?

Comment: - about the overhead issue, there's a checking about the existing of accessoryView in the 'if' clause, or you can use the NSAutoreleasePool technique to resolve it. Place the statement 'NSAutorelease *pool = [[NSAutorelease alloc] init];' at the first line of the function, and '[pool release]' at the last line of the function
- about the animation, there's no way to resolve